# How to fit the model for crossed and nested design using lme function in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Suppose A is a fixed factor and B is a random factor. A and B are crossed. Another random factor C is nested in B. Taking into account the AB and AC interactions, how should I fit the model using lme function in the nlme package? Thanks.

Comment: You mention the lme package on the title, and nlme on your question. Which is the correct package?

Comment: AND .... where's the code?

Comment: I said the lme function in the nlme package. lme is not a package. And I'm just wondering how to specify the arguments in this function for my problem.

Comment: Have you tried `lmer()` in the lme4 package? See e.g. [this book chapter](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/book/Ch2.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, the lmer() function can deal with crossed random effects easily. That is why the lme4 package is a big improvement for the nlme package. I realized later that it was really hard to use lme() function to fit crossed random effects. Since we've got the newer package, why not use it？

Answer (score 5):

The tricky part here is to specify the right formula.

```
library(nlme)
# Assume y is your response variable.
lme(fixed = y ~ A, random = ~ A | B/C)
```

Here `B/C` stands for C nested in B and is short for `B + B:C`. The interaction with A is present because A is repeated in the random part.

For a basic introduction to nlme, I recommend [this document](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fdoc%2Fcontrib%2FFox-Companion%2Fappendix-mixed-models.pdf&ei=B6PKT-jyGMGW0QWItYHMAQ&usg=AFQjCNGjGcZ-o8isfsGWcNYT6PWkkQFLhA&sig2=_drpm-i_YpITr-1HpZ_hvg).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I think you are right. I will use a practical example to check it. By the way, really nice reference. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried the formula you mentioned using R. Unfortunately, the data set I used did not justify the formula. The lme() function applied simply did not converge to a numerical solution. Seems that the lmer() function in the lme4 package does the right thing.